# Coproduct of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

Can anyone explain why the coproduct of groups are the free product?

For finite groups, the products are direct products which are also finite. But the free groups are infinite? So the coproduct is larger than the product?

Comment: What specifically is confusing you?  Do you remember the definition of the coproduct?  Do you know what the canonical injections look like for groups?  Are you having trouble verifying the required universal property?

Comment: Note by the way that products are not in general “larger” than coproducts.  For in any category you can consider the opposite category, in which the products and coproducts are exchanged. If the products were bigger (in any sense) in the original category, they will be smaller (in whatever sense that is) in the opposite category. For example you can make the integers into a category by saying there is a single morphism from $a$ to $b$ exactly when $a$ divides $b$. Then the product of $12$ and $18$ is $6$ and the coproduct is $36$.

Comment: For products, any group $H$ with $f:H\rightarrow A$ and $g:H\rightarrow B$, I can define $\phi:H\rightarrow A\times B$ by $\phi(h)=(f(h),g(h))$, right? What about coproduct?

Comment: You really mean "free product" not "free group".

Comment: It sounds from your comment that you don't understand what the canonical injections look like but I wish you would fix your question to explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: By the way, the free product of $G$ and $H$ even when one group, say $H$, is trivial, is of the form ${g_1 i g_2 i \cdots g_k i}$. Isn't there still infinitely such elements?

Comment: In the free group construction, the two identity elements of the two groups are identified, so that there is only one identity element in the free group.  Then $g_1ig_2 = g_1g_2$, and if $H$ is trivial the products in the free product of $G$ and $H$ always reduce to single elements of $G$. Then the free product of $G$ and a trivial $H$ is isomorphic to $G$, as you would expect.  Is your problem that you don't know how a free group is constructed?

Comment: I am new to category theory and it's really difficult to understand. Any suggested materials for beginners?

Comment: If there exist surjective homomorphisms $f:M\rightarrow N$ and $g:N\rightarrow M$, is it true that one can conclude that both $f$ and $g$ are isomorphisms?

Comment: No, not in general, but that is a theorem of group theory, not of category theory.

Answer (score 1):

Well, neither for positive integers, addition is *not always* bigger than mulitplication: just think about $1\cdot 1\cdot 1 < 1+1+1$. So we shouldn't expect anything like $X\times Y \ge X+Y$  in general (whatever these symbols would mean).

By a (group) *presentation* we mean a syntactic entity: a pair $\langle X,\Gamma\rangle$ where $X$ is a set (of 'variables') and elements are $\Gamma$ are *relations* $(\tau,\sigma)$ (interpreted as '$\tau=\sigma$') using words $\tau,\ \sigma$ from the free group on alphabet $X$. 
*Note.* For groups, a relation $\tau=\sigma$ of course can be written up using only one term, stating $\tau\sigma^{-1}=1$, but the same construction works for general algebraic structures as well.

Now, consider the category ${\bf Pres}$ of presentations with functions $f:X\to Y$ as arrows $\langle X,\Gamma\rangle\to \langle Y,\Delta\rangle$ which satisfy $(\tau,\sigma)\in\Gamma\ \implies (f(\tau),\,f(\sigma))\in\Delta$.

Coproduct in this category is simply disjoint union, and the 'free' functor ${\bf Pres}\to{\bf Grp}$ (sending  $\langle X,\Gamma\rangle\ \mapsto \ F(X)/(\Gamma)\,$) has a right adjoint $G\mapsto \langle G,\{$all valid equations of $G\}\rangle$, so **it preserves coproduct**.